# use plain JDK api to implement HDFS?

Tags: hdfs

i want to use the plain JDK api to implement the read and write mechanism in the HDFS? but doc or reference i can find are all about how to use the HDFS api? anyone can give me some suggestion about this? reference or code both is ok? much thanks.

Comment: Can be useful for a good start   http://princetonits.com/blog/technology/using-filesystem-api-to-read-and-write-data-to-hdfs/

Comment: Much thanks let me take a look